# In Python, how to time execution time of a function with an outer function that takes an inner function as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

*Python 3.7 (WinOS, VS Code)*

#### I WANT

I want to have a timer function in my library to use in a certain way. If there already is such a function available through `from something import what_i_need`, please let me know.

The best way to use a function for me would be such that I can simply wrap whatever function which returns something in this timer function `time(...)` instead of in `print(...)`, so I don't have to change anything but that when I want to test execution time.

```py
print(add(2, 3))
"""output:
5
"""

time(add(2, 3))
"""output:
---
Result: 5
Execution time: 7.000000010748408e-07
"""
```

...but it would also have to be acceptable (if it cannot be done the other way) to have to use like this:

```py
time(add, 2, 3)
```

#### I HAVE part 1: The correct result without a function

It's easy to time execution in a variety of ways (are any others better than `perf_counter`?). One such is the following:

```py
from time import perf_counter

t_start = perf_counter()
print("---\nResult: ", add(2, 3), "\nExecution time: ", perf_counter() - t_start, sep="")
```

#### I HAVE part 2: A function without the correct result

I made a working function, that easily accepts any function in a way I like the most, but I came to realize it's useless, since the inner function is executed before the time is measured:

```py
from time import perf_counter

def time(function):
  t_start = perf_counter()
  print("---\nResult: ", function, "\nExecution time: ", perf_counter() - t_start, sep="")

time(add(2, 3))
```

#### BONUS

If I could use it like `time(add(b=3, a=2))` or `time(add, b=3, a=2)` where `def add(a=0, b=0): return a + b` it would be even better.

Comment: The description in your title is inconsistent with this: `time(add(2, 3))` That function doesn't take a function, it is being passed the result of *calling* a function, the function is already done executing before `time` is called. You probably just want to look at the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html) module

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I think the title is OK. This only means, that the other solution I also mentioned is the right one (`time(add, 2, 3)`). I checked `timeit` and it's an awesome timer, since you can the average time execution over many loops. Thanks! But I still can't time the ONE TIME execution of the function and get the result at the same time, so I could use my timer function instead of `print`. @juanpa.arrivillaga